# Django POST - unable to retrieve form data, POST check fails

Tags: python, django, post

I'm very new to Django. I am trying to desing my login module and trying to print the values i submit.

1. login.html (please excuse indentation mistakes)

   ```
   {% load staticfiles %}

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Login Form</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/lstyle.css' %}"> 
   </head>

   <body>
   {% block content %}
   {% if form.errors %}
       <script> alert("Your username and password didn't match. Please try 
   again."); </script>
   {% endif %}

   {% if next %}
   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
       <script> alert("Your account doesn't have access to this page. To 
       proceed,please login with an account that has access."); </script>
   {% else %}
       <script> alert('Please login'); </script>
   {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
   <div class="login">
       <div class="login-screen">
           <div class="app-title">
               <h1>Login</h1>
           </div>
           <div class="login-form">
                   <form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
                       <p class="bs-component">
                           <table>
                               <tr>
                                   <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
                               </tr>
                               <tr>
                                   <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
                              </tr>
                               <tr>
                                   <td>{{ form.schoolID }}</td>
                               </tr>
                           </table>
                       </p>
                       <p class="bs-component">
                           <center>
                               <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
                               type="submit" value="login" />
                           </center>
                       </p>
                       <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" 
                       />
                   </form>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </body>
   {% endblock %}
   </html>
   ```
2. Forms.py

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
   from django import forms


   # If you don't do this you cannot use Bootstrap CSS
   class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
         username = forms.CharField(max_length=30,
                          widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 
                          'form-control', 'name': 'username', 'placeholder': 'Username'}))
         password = forms.CharField(max_length=30,
                          widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 
                          'form-control', "name": 'password', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
         schoolID = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                          widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 
                          'form-control', 'name': 'schoolid', 'placeholder': 'School ID'}))
   ```
3. Views.py

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
   from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
   from home.forms import LoginForm
   from home.models import UserProfile
   from django.views.generic import TemplateView
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User


   @login_required(login_url="login/")
   def home(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
           myform = LoginForm(request.POST)
           print(myform.data['schoolID'])
           return render(request, "home.html")
   ```

Things working:

1. html file renders perfectly.
2. User authentication works
3. if the "return render(request, "home.html")" is placed outside the if block, the code runs perfectly, and i am redirected to home.html - by entering matching username and password.

Things not working:

1. Unable to print schoolID. i.e, the "if request.method == 'POST':" is not being executed.
2. The error: The view home.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

what am i doing wrong here. I just want to print the form data and do operations with it before i execute the return statement. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

use `myform = LoginForm(data=request.POST)`

OR `myform = LoginForm(None , request.POST)`

because request is not the first parameter.